Where to edit {site.message_header}?
I cannot find where to go to edit our {site.message_header} ? It is referred to in various places, but no link to it.

Administer - Communications - Site Tokens
url: civicrm/admin/sitetoken

no, it's not there for me - could it be somewhere else? I do have full Admin access as far as I know...

What version are you on? It was added in 5.76

version 5.37 - where would it be for this version?

It wouldn't be anywhere for that version. The token is pretty new.
